# Detect Rectangle Border On a page [ OpencCV ]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to detect the black rectangle on the page. Basically I want to crop the image inside it.[image: Sample Picture]

Line thickness can be increased a bit but I think this should be enough. Thanks in advance for the solution.
Cheers

Comment: Sure, provide me with your address so I can send you a bill for $100 a hour... We are not your private software developers... I suggest trying to find a solution of your own first.

Comment: Well I actually have tired to find but there was nothing much online so I posted it and I am working to find my solution too and if I will find it I will answer my own question.

Comment: Like hell there is nothing to find: https://github.com/alyssaq/opencv https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/

Comment: this is not what I am looking detecting square is not difficult and which I have done already. I am looking to find the area between the black rectangle. https://ibb.co/mktrEw go to this image and you will get what I am not talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my steps:

1. read and convert to gray;
2. threshold the gray;
3. find the max-area contour, fill it to make the mask;
4. do `bitwise_and` on the original to crop it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer again but this will not work if I will take the picture of complete picture (like the document scanner). I need to make sure that only this rectangle is being detected as my contour area.

Comment: I only answer for the certain condition, not for the assumption. If it does not work, just put the condition and the non-work result.

Comment: https://ibb.co/mktrEw I was talking about this kind of issue. I only want to detect the black line as my contour. 
Thanks

Comment: Threshould，find the max white  region, copyto white background. Then do this question becomes to  that type.